# Limit with Arctan

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Here's a hard limit I've been trying to answer for a while :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \dfrac{-2x\arctan{x} + \dfrac{\pi}{2}}{x-1}$$

I've tried all the tricks that the teacher has taught us and still nothing, I even tried to factor the top by $(x-1)$ but still nothing. Can I get some help on how to evaluate this limit please?

Comment: it's good to use latex in www.codecogs.com or use mathtype for write your equation in here:)

Comment: and for show a comment is useful you can use vote up that comment :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac\pi2 - 2x\arctan x}{x-1}
&= 2 \frac{\frac\pi4 - x\arctan x}{x-1} \\
&= 2\left(\frac{\frac\pi4 - \arctan x}{x-1} - \arctan x\right) \\
&= 2\left(\frac{\arctan 1 - \arctan x}{x-1} - \arctan x\right) \\
&= 2\left(\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x-1} - \arctan x\right) \\
&= 2\left(\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}\cdot\frac{-1}{1+x} - \arctan x\right)
\end{align*}
Recall that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$; from this it follows that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1$; from that it follows that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{\arctan x} = 1$; and note that $\frac{1-x}{1+x}\to 0$ as $x\to 1$.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help but I have one question, in the second line when you factored by with 2 is it -Arctan(x) or -xArctan(x)?

Comment: in the first line it's $x\arctan x$, which I treat as $(x-1)\arctan x + \arctan x$ to get to the second line.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much for you're help.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if we write $f(x) = -2x\arctan(x)$, then your limit is the formal definition of $f'(1)$.

Hence you can calculate the limit by calculating that derivative using standard results: $\displaystyle f'(x) = -2\arctan(x)  - \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$, thus ...

Comment: It is a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

in cases which have (0/0) or (inf/inf) you can use (Hopital's rule):

[image]

so:
[image]

and this is easily can be calculated.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention that we still haven't learn hopital's rule so we can't use it yet.

Comment: can you use Teylor series?

Comment: Nope we still haven't learned that either.